# Postgres: to_tsvector duplicate lexemes

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, tsvector

**My Statement:**

```
SELECT to_tsvector ('english','Our first string used today first string');
```

**My Result:**

```
'first':2 'first':6  'string':3 'string':7  'today':5  'use':4
```

**My Question:**
Why does "My Result" duplicate lexemes `first` and `string`?

**My expected result:**

```
'first':2,6 'string':3,7 'today':5 'use':4
```

**My Postgres version:**
PostgreSQL 9.2.2, compiled by Visual C++ build 1600, 64-bit



I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: It is equivalent to "select '1' from dual" in Oracle.

Comment: weird, expected result should be sorted 1st, and I cannot reproduce it on version 9.4 - result is the following : `'first':2,6 'string':3,7 'today':5 'use':4`

Comment: same result in 9.3: `'first':2,6 'string':3,7 'today':5 'use':4`

Comment: I have included in my post some debug information, obtained through this stament: SELECT ts_debug ('english', 'Our first string used today first string'); Dmitry is right: expected result should be sorted 1st. Thanks Dmitry and Neil!

Comment: Grateful for all the help you can give me. Thanks!